# Role of the browser vs. the role of an advertiser?

Tags: ios8, multipeer-connectivity

I am trying to understand the explicit roles between a browser object and an advertiser object regarding who controls the session. I can not find an adequate analogy regarding how connections are established with MPC. For example, does an advertiser object advertise the service and if so, why does the browser object invite the advertiser to a session? Or does the advertiser advertise its ability to connect to a valid session? The Apple docs state the following:

> You should also set up an advertiser or advertiser assistant to allow
>   other devices to ask your app to join a session that they create.

Is "they" the browser or the advertiser?

Are the session objects required to use MPC exchanged upon connection, meaning once connection utilizes two sessions to communicate? For example, the browser object finds a peer and invites it to the session owned by the device browsing:

```
 [browser invitePeer:peerID toSession:self.session withContext:nil timeout:kTimeout];
```

Then the advertiser receives the invitation passing its own separate session object through a callback:

```
 invitationHandler(YES, self.session);
```

Are these sessions shared between the devices or is one used exclusively?

I am trying to build a mental model of how MPC works under the hood, but I cannot find a satisfactory analogy.